# pattern followed with no more digit regular expression python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a list containing multiple values such as:

```
l = [
 '210-4521268-18',
 '210.0622277.13', 
 'rachid 312-0653348-08',
 '3000401732 00000 064 77063',
 ....,
 '312-0653348-08 rachid'
]
```

I want to fetch only items with the format "210.0622277.13" corresponding to the following regular expression:

```
r'\d{3}\D?\d{7}\D?\d{2}'
```

so far I have written the following regular expression to fetch theses values:

```
regex = re.compile(r'((\d{3}\D?\d{7}\D?\d{2}$)|(^\d{3}\D?\d{7}\D?\d{2}))')
# loop through the list to fetch desired part of value
for line in l:
   match = regex.search(line)
   if match:
       print('line : {} found a match {}'.format(line, line[match.start():match.end()]))
   else:
      print('line : {} found no match'.format(line)
```

the problem is that the value '3000401732 00000 064 77063' gets matched

how can I refine this regular expression to not accept no more digits after the desired pattern in case there's more digits after the pattern the value will be discarded.

the matches I need to catch are:

```
l = [
   '210-4521268-18',
   '210.0622277.13', 
   '312-0653348-08',
   '312-0653348-08'
]
```

so the output will be something like:

```
line : 210-4521268-18 found a match 210-4521268-18
line : 210.0622277.13 found a match 210.0622277
line : rachid 312-0653348-08 found a match 312-0653348-08
line : 3000401732 00000 064 77063 found no match
line : 312-0653348-08 rachid found a match 312-0653348-08
```

Comment: If you want to anchor the pattern to the beginning of the line, you can prefix it with `^`, and if you want to anchor it to the end of the line, you can suffix it with `$`.  So to match an entire line, you can enclose the pattern in `^` and `$`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
\d{3}[^\d]\d{7}[^\d]\d{2}
```

Live demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/HHz0rx/2)

**Explanation**:

`\d{3}` : look for 3 digits

`[^\d]\d{7}`: look for a non-digit, then look for 7 digits

`[^\d]\d{2}`: again look for a non-digit, then look for 2 digits

Comment: btw if you don't want the separator to be a space (or anything else) you can simply add `\s`(or another character) to the set like this : `[^\d\s]` or if you've a list of allowed separators you can simply use it like this: `[\-\.]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
l = [
'210-4521268-18',
'210.0622277.13', 
'rachid 312-0653348-08',
'3000401732 00000 064 77063',
'312-0653348-08 rachid'
]
final_vals = [re.findall('\d+[\W]\d+[\W]\d+', i)[0] for i in l if re.findall('\d+\.|-\d+\.|-\d+', i)]
```

Output:

```
['210-4521268-18', '210.0622277.13', '312-0653348-08', '312-0653348-08']
```

Comment: please see the edits I made for the question sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach:

```
l = [
 '210-4521268-18',
 '210.0622277.13',
 'rachid 312-0653348-08',
 '3000401732 00000 064 77063',
 '312-0653348-08 rachid'
]

regex = re.compile(r'\d{3}(?:\.|-)\d{7}(?:\.|-)\d{2}')    
for line in l:
   match = regex.search(line)
   if match:
       print('line : {} found a match {}'.format(line, match.group()))
   else:
       print('line : {} found no match'.format(line))
```

The output:

```
line : 210-4521268-18 found a match 210-4521268-18
line : 210.0622277.13 found a match 210.0622277.13
line : rachid 312-0653348-08 found a match 312-0653348-08
line : 3000401732 00000 064 77063 found no match
line : 312-0653348-08 rachid found a match 312-0653348-08
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are valid matches - that string is in the strings returned.

Try adding ^ at the front and/or $ at the back, or some other way to specify that the additional data will fail the match.

```
regex = re.compile(r'^((\d{3}\D?\d{7}\D?\d{2}$)|(^\d{3}\D?\d{7}\D?\d{2}))$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter by dot "." like this:

```
import re

l = [
 '210-4521268-18',
 '210.0622277.13', 
 'rachid 312-0653348-08',
 '3000401732 00000 064 77063',
 '312-0653348-08 rachid'
]

regex = re.compile(r'\b(\w+[.]\w+)')
# loop through the list to fetch desired part of value
for line in l:
   match = regex.search(line)
   if match:
       print('line : {} found a match {}'.format(line, line[match.start():match.end()]))
   else:
      print('line : {} found no match'.format(line))
```

As result I get:

```
line : 210-4521268-18 found no match
line : 210.0622277.13 found a match 210.0622277
line : rachid 312-0653348-08 found no match
line : 3000401732 00000 064 77063 found no match
line : 312-0653348-08 rachid found no match
```

Comment: please see the edits I made for the question sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Try specify dots explicity and mark begin and end.

```
r'^\d{3}[^\d]\d{7}[^\d]\d{3}$'
```

Comment: for the value 'rachid 312-0653348-08' I need to fetch '312-0653348-08', so your regular expression won't reach the goal 100%, thanks any way

Comment: Yes, that matched only `.` To match non-digit one can use `[^\d]`.